# Do I really need to $ source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash?

Tags: ros, path, message, rospack, source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Novice question:

I've created a custom message, package, etc as the official tutorial does. But when i do:

$ rosrun pkg_test1 pkg_test1_node

it gives me: [rospack] Error: package 'pkg_test1' not found

Indeed, if i do: $ source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash the problem is fixed. But do i really need to do that every time i want to use my custom programs? Is there any simple way to mantain them in the ROS path (i think that is what i am doing when i call these commands).

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229365/do-i-really-need-to-$-source-%7E/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash-?/) by [thepirate16](https://answers.ros.org/users/26128/thepirate16/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2016-03-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you really do need to source a `setup.bash` file in every single terminal that you want to use ROS in. These scripts control many important [ROS environment variables](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/EnvironmentVariables) and non-ROS environment variables (PYTHONPATH, CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH, etc.). The `setup.bash` scripts provide a convenient way to control which version of ROS is "active" and which workspaces are "active" (see page on [overlaying workspaces](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying)).

If you want every terminal to automatically "source" a particular `setup.bash` script, you could put that command in your `~/.bashrc`. See the [Environment Setup](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu#indigo.2BAC8-Installation.2BAC8-DebEnvironment.Environment_setup) section of the ROS installation instructions.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2016-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thepirate16](https://answers.ros.org/users/26128/thepirate16/) on 2016-03-17**:
Ok! Now i understand it! Thanks for the reply!

**Comment by [cartucho](https://answers.ros.org/users/52844/cartucho/) on 2020-03-25**:
Shouldn't `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` be enough? Do I really need to do `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` every single time that I want to use my custom packages?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-25**:
@cartucho: no, it cannot be enough.

`/opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` only "knows about" the packages installed under `/opt/ros/kinetic`. It contains no references to your own, custom packages in your `catkin_ws`. So if you `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash`, you only get access to the packages installed there.

What you don't need to do is `source` *both* the `setup.bash` in `/opt/ros/kinetic` *and* your `catkin_ws`. Just `source`ing your `catkin_ws` should be sufficient to get you access to both sets of packages (provided you have setup your own workspace correctly).

**Comment by [cartucho](https://answers.ros.org/users/52844/cartucho/) on 2020-03-25**:
thank you @gvdhoorn it worked!